# Extracting gene location from FASTA file

Tags: python, python-3.x, biopython

I am trying to extract the gene location from a fasta file using BioPython but the function .location is not working. I would like to avoid regex because this function will have to work with different files and the all have slightly different headers.

The header looks like:
 >X dna:chromosome chromosome:GRCh38:X:111410060:111411807:-1

I would like the output to be:
start = 111410060
end = 111411807

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to help you, we need to see the code that you are asking about. Please take a few moments to create an post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the headers of your different fasta files always end with '**...chr:start:end:strand**' and the different parts are separated by '**:**' you could try to split .description by `.split(":")` and select the penultimate and antepenultimate  position of the resulting list.

The following works for me with your example header:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
path = 'fasta_test.fasta'
records = SeqIO.parse(open(path), 'fasta')
record = next(records)
parts = record.description.split(":")
print('start =', parts[-3], 'end =', parts[-2])
```